# install MATLAB directly on raspberrypi

Tags: raspbian, matlab

I know there are some tools for MATLAB-RPi connection e.g. using simulink add-ons and blocks. But is it possible to install MATLAB directly on RPi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  [MATLAB is only available for the Intel x86 architecture](http://www.mathworks.com/products/availability/) while the Raspberry Pi uses an [ARM processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture).

However you [*can* install Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) which has much of the functionality of MATLAB, including alternatives to many of the MATLAB toolboxes, and is available for the RPi for free.

You can also install [GNU Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) using `apt-get install octave`.  Octave is a MATLAB clone.

The [J language](http://www.jsoftware.com/) (an APL variant) is also available for the Raspberry Pi and is a viable alternative for the base MATLAB language (though not the toolboxes).  [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [Python + numpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numpy) are great for number crunching too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Raspberry Pi as a target board in simulink and Matlab. Have a look at:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/raspberry-pi.html

http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-matlab.html

Comment: It should be noted that this only works with the Windows version of MATLAB.  With the Mac and Linux versions it does not work.